# Using table reference in worksheetfunction

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, listobject

I'm trying to use `WorksheetFunction` with table reference as arguments and it's not working.

```
Function Index_Formula(TBL As ListObject, TBLSource As ListObject) As Double
  TBL.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(TBLSource.DataBodyRange, _
    TBL.ListColumns(1), TBL.ListColumns(2))
End Function
```

I could get away with it by using `For each Loop`, but I'm trying to avoid it whenever I can to make the code faster.

Comment: What would this look like as a regular INDEX function? `TBL.ListColumns(1), TBL.ListColumns(2)` don't make sense as the row and column arguments.

Comment: As is, your function isn't returning anything either... possibly should be a `Sub`?

Comment: It is resulting in an error. I want to call this function more than once. That's why I'm usind function code.

Comment: You can call a `Sub` more than once... I don't understand your reasoning here.

Comment: I thought I could get away with ````TBL.ListColumns(1), TBL.ListColumns(2)```` because if record the macro, it would be like this ````.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(TBName,[Line],[Column])"````

Comment: That is [implicit intersection](https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection) but that doesn't work here.

Comment: For a second I was confused as to what would you want to use [tabla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla) in a worksheetfunction :D

Comment: *Table, Typo. sorry

Comment: no worries. I fixed it already.

Comment: @BigBen. ````Function```` makes my code look cleaner, but I can change to ````Sub````. But due to implicit intersection, I can't table's reference as arguments in ````WorksheetFunction````?

Comment: This may be an XY-problem. Can you explain what your end goal is, what you are trying to do? You need arguments for the row number and column number that resolve to just a single number, which is what happens in the formula `"=INDEX(TBName,[Line],[Column])"` when used in a table. But that approach doesn't work in VBA.

Comment: I'm trying to fill the the ````TBL.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange```` with the results of an index function, according to each row at ````TBL.ListColumns(1)TBL.ListColumns(2)````. But I don't want to access the spreadsheet every time it prints the result in each cell.

Comment: Options I can think of: create an array of the results and output the array in one step. Or write the actual INDEX formula (here you *can* use implicit intersection) into the 3rd column in one step, and convert to values if needed.

Comment: @BigBen!! The array solution worked. thank you.